# Measurement of Spin in different directions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

imagine you have an electron in the spin state $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(i,1)^T$, which is an eigenvector of the Pauli Matrix for y-direction.

Now I want to know what are the possible results for measurement in z-direction. Of course, it is clear that it must be either $\tfrac 12\hbar$ or $-\tfrac 12\hbar$. But I am confused with the associated eigenvalue equations.

A measurement of spin z direction would mean that we apply the spin operator for z direction to our spin state $x$.
But when I do this, I get: $S_z \cdot x= \tfrac 12\hbar y$, where y is almost equal to $x$ but with switched signs of the components. I expected it to be equal to $x$.
Where am I going wrong?
Ok, I see that the vector $x$ might not be an eigenvector of $S_z$ but then how do we set up a proper equation?

EDIT: Or is it as simple as just saying that in any spin state, the possible values for measuring spin in any direction (x,y,z)  in the spin state are h/2 or -h/2?

Comment: The process of measurement of an observable $\hat{A}$ does *not* correspond to the mathematical operation of acting with $\hat{A}$ on the state.

Comment: Got it, so it just corresponds to the eigenstates of the operator.

Comment: did you really call a $\sigma_y$ eigenstate $x$?...or do you mean $\chi_y$......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the operator to a state is not the same as a measurement. To perform a measurement you have to look at the eigenvectors of the operator. The $S_z$ operator has the eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1}$ in the z-basis.

After the measurement, the state is in either of those eigenstates. The probability of getting a certain outcome is given by the overlap of the state with the eigenvector:

\begin{align}
p(\uparrow)&=\left|\langle \uparrow|x\rangle\right|^2\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\pmatrix{-i& 1}\pmatrix{1\\0}\right|^2\\
&=\frac 1 2
\end{align}

A nice, equivalent way of this process is achieved by expanding your vector in the basis of your measurement operator and then reading of the coefficients. If your measurement operator is Hermitian its eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis and we can always do this.
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle=\alpha_1|1\rangle+\alpha_2|2\rangle+\alpha_3|3\rangle\\
\implies p(1)=|\alpha_1|^2=|\langle1|\psi\rangle|^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question:

*"Or is it as simple as just saying that in any spin state, the possible values for measuring spin in any direction (x,y,z) in the spin state are h/2 or -h/2?"*

1. It's $\hbar/2$
2. The question hints at a few misunderstandings, which I'll try to address:

For any angular momentum quantum number $j$, the possible eigenstates of the projection operator onto any axis ($\hbar=1$) are:

$$ m = (-j, -j+1, \cdots, j-1, j) $$

Spin half ($j=\frac 1 2$) is a special case with $m=\pm \frac 1 2$.

Note that it is *any* axis. The $z$ axis is not special, both in name, nor physically. It is totally arbitrary.

We just use $z$-axis so we can write down non-ambiguous mathematical expressions. One reason the $z$-axis works best is because it is how polar coordinate are defined: the polar angle $\theta$ is defined relative to the $z$-axis, and the azimuth angle $\phi$ from the $x$-axis.

While that coordinate system is *not* arbitrary when making maps of the Earth (well, Greenwich is somewhat arbitrary), it is arbitrary when defining spin states or atomic orbitals.

The spin states (in $z$-is-the-preferred-axis-notation, up to a global phase convention):

$$\chi^+_{\theta, \phi}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta/2\\e^{i\phi}\sin\theta/2}$$
$$\chi^-_{\theta, \phi}=\pmatrix{e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta/2\\\cos\theta/2}$$

are the $\pm \frac 1 2$ eigenstates relative to the axis defined by the polar angles.

You can define secondary polar angles relative to this axis, and you'll find that, after a lot of trig, the direction of the axis is physically meaningless, so lets use:

$$\chi^+=\pmatrix{1\\0}$$
$$\chi^-=\pmatrix{0\\1}$$

and call it the $z$-axis.

Again: it's *any* axis. In the question, you single out the coordinate bases $(x, y, z)$, which are also not special, and have no physical meaning. That they are orthogonal means that any eigenstate along one direction
is a 50-50 mix of the eigenstates along either of the other two:

$$\chi^{\pm}_i = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}
\big(
\chi^+_{j, k}e^{i\alpha_{j,k}} +
\chi^-_{j, k}e^{i\beta_{j,k}}
\big)
$$

Where the $\alpha_{j,k}, \beta_{j,k}$ are phase factors depending on the choices of $(i,j,k)$ as realizations of $(x, y, z)$.

This may sound trivial, but it results from rotational symmetry. For any angular momentum $j$, a state with fixed $|j, m\rangle_z$ can be represented as states quantized on a different axis ($z'$):

$$ |j, m\rangle_z = \sum_{m'=-j}^{m'+=j}a_{jmm'}|j, m'\rangle_{z'}$$

So rotations mix $m$, but keep $j$ fixed.(For specific examples, look into rotating spherical harmonics, or Wigner $d$ matrices).

What it means is that the $2j+1$ states transform as an irreducible representation of
the rotation group ($SO(3)$ for integer $j$, and $SU(2)$ for half-integer).

It's the whole reason we use angular momentum.